# Java, single database column referencing multiple times

Tags: java, database, jpa, relationship

I have this relationship in one table like this:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TEAM_HOME", nullable=false)
    private Team team;

    @Column(name="TEAM_AWAY", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int teamAway;
```

And this relationship in other:

```
    @XmlTransient
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="team",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Result> result;
```

I want to reference one column from table Team multiple times in table Result, bet I don't know how. I have tried different ways but without success.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. Can you be more precise? Do you want a @ManyToMany Relationship? Or do you want to turn teamAway into a ManyToOne towards Team?

Comment: it would also help to see a bit more of your classes, like names etc.

Comment: I have two tables - Team and Results. Team table contain information about teams(team name.....) and Results table contain information about results. Teams are competing against each other. What I want to do is to place in Results table information about teams competition results. Results table must contain columns: TeamHome, TeamAway, ScoreHome, ScoreAway, where both(TeamHome and TeamAway) are referencing from table Teams.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two Relations from Team to Result:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="teamHome",...)
private Set<Result> resultsHome;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="teamAway",...)
private Set<Result> resultsAway;
```

but nothing stops you from adding methods like

```
public Set<Result> getResults() {
    Set<Result> results = new HashSet<>();
    results.addAll(resultsHome);
    results.addAll(resultsAway);
    return results;
}

public void addResult(Result result) {
    if (result.teamHome == this) {
        resultsHome.add(result);
    } else {
        resultsAway.add(result);
    }
}
```

I guess this is not what you were hoping for. But putting all Results in the same collection would not be correct as it is something different. After all, you would probably want something like the inverse result for your "away"-matches in that collection.

You should really ask yourself if you really want those 2 Relations in your Team class. Wouldn't a DAO.getMatchesForTeam(...) serve the same purpose? When you really want to make a model of sports events, you might end up with plenty of relations in Team and it will clutter up your code. The @XMLTransient annotation already indicates that the results aren't that important to the team for them to be transported to the client.

Oh and btw: There is something between team and result: the match. The result should only hold the result. That way you can make a Result.inverse() method that will give you the result from the other team's perspective. But there is nothing like a Match.inverse() because the home team will always be the home team.